# Flutter: Androidx.window:window requires compileSDKVersion to set to 31 or higher

Tags: flutter

Am using a plugin which has a compile SDK set to 28, but looks like with Flutter 3.0 compile SDK is set to 31. So whenever I am building I get this error:

```
Dependency 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 31 or higher.
Compilation target for module ':app' is 'android-28'
```

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `android` module of your app, find the file `build.gradle` and set the property `compileSdk` value to 31